# Which free database (other than SQL Express) has SQL syntax most similar to T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I think there is an upgrade/downgrade path between MySQL and DB2 because they are both pretty ANSI standards compliant.

Other than SQL Express, is there a similar pairing of free-"ish"/paid databases for SQL Server?

Another way to state the question-- of the free db engines that exist, which is the least painful to migrate T-SQL to?

Update-- 
Background:  I'm looking for a suitable downgrade path. I wrote an app that I wanted to post to codeplex and then I realized that the likely audience might not have admin rights, wouldn't be able to cope with the administrativia of MS-SQL, etc.

Comment: @rexem What about it? If I have a lot of TSQL, will it be relatively easy or painful to translate it into PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a free version of Sybase ASE available; Sybase supports T-SQL.

Answer (score 4):

One of Microsoft's big advantages with Sql Server over other offerings is that they have a complete compatible solution, no matter where you are on the size-spectrum: from simple desktop engines with SQL Server Compact Edition all the way to massive warehouses with SQL Server Enterprise Edition, you can be confident that there's an upgrade path for *your* data.  The idea seems to be that if your data scales beyond what SQL Server Express Edition can handle, you're doing well enough in your business to afford one of the more expensive editions.

This is *especially* true because once you're into that scale migrating to another database is not trivial and will be expensive in it's own right.  Once your system is that large and complex even simple differences between database engines can be a big deal.  Fortunately for most of us, Express Edition is pretty capable.

So in most cases the next upgrade path from SQL Server is... SQL Server.  If your database is big enough that a free edition won't cut it, it's big enough that we really need to know exactly what your goals are and what you are trying to accomplish to give you a good recommendation on an alternative.

Comment: I agree-- I update my question with more back ground.  I definitely agree that if someone thinks their small DB will turn into a bid department level or enterpise wide application, they should stick with an upgrade path going from SQL Express to paid editions of SQL.  But all editions of SQL are a significant administrative hassle for the smallest apps.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL is probably the closest that I've used. Postgres is special in its own way, and doesn't do a lot of what T-SQL does. SQLite is lacking too many functions to even come close.

That being said, the most pain you'll run into (I've found)  is around string and column manipulations. MySQL often offers a direct translation, if not that function, at least in my experience.